# Spring BatchSqlUpdate is not executing rest of the SQL after one fail

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Is there any way to continue to execute all the SQL using BatchSqlUpdate of Spring even if one of the SQL failed ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is no.

Springs batch update firstly checks to see if the underlying connection supports batch updates.

If it does then you will have to check if the provider of your JDBC driver supports continuing on a failure.

If it doesn't then spring will run each statement in turn. If any one of the statements fails an Exception is thrown.